# Collection-repeat and checked input type checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a collection of contacts and I generate an `ion-item` for each contact using `collection-repeat`. Each ion-item has a span, a paragraph and a checkbox element within it. I chose to use collection-repeat over `ng-repeat` because it increases performance.

I understand that `collection-repeat` only renders the items that can fit the screen at once and renders more as we scroll.

The problem I have is that when I click a checkbox within an item, for example, the first one, and scroll down to see more lists, another checkbox within an item lower in the list would also be checked automatically. This is not the intended behaviour as I want users to be able to check a checkbox for every item.

These pictures will make the explanation clearer:

[image]

Why is my list showing this behaviour? Does it have to do with how collection-repeat works or is it a problem with my code? This is really killing me and I need to find answers. Thanks!

Comment: I know very little about collection-repeat, but in my experience, this problem is common in list views, no matter the implementation. Generally it's caused by the view reusing a component - in this case, it looks like it's reused item one. Try clearing all values when the item is first created, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic team is working on it right now https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1806